# Drop Columns in multiple tables that have Column Name similar to values in another Table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, match

I need help with a requirement. I am able to manually complete the requirement but hoping this could be automated. Please see below.

1. DB has many tables.
2. One of the tables 'TblMaster' has 2 columns.

   a. CName
   b. Flag

   Sample Table (TblMaster) Creation Code:

```
    CREATE TABLE TblMaster (CName varchar(30), Flag int)
    INSERT INTO TblMaster (cname,flag) values ('ABC',0);
    INSERT INTO TblMaster (cname,flag) values ('DEF',1);
    INSERT INTO TblMaster (cname,flag) values ('GHI',1);
    INSERT INTO TblMaster (cname,flag) values ('JKL',1);
    INSERT INTO TblMaster (cname,flag) values ('MNO',1);
```

3. There could be several other tables in the DB that has one or more columns with string content 'CName' from the table 'TblMaster'.

   Sample Tables (TB1 and TB2) Creation Code:

```
   
    CREATE TABLE TB1 
    (
       ABC int ,
       ABC1 int, 
       ABC2 int,
       DEF varchar(30),
       DEF1 varchar(30),
       DEF2 varchar(30),
       GHI varchar(30),
       GHI1 varchar(30),
       JKL numeric,
       JKL1 numeric,
       MNO datetime,
       MNO1 datetime,
       NOTEXIST varchar(30),
       NOTEXIST1 varchar(30), 
       NOTEXIST2 varchar(30)  
    )

    INSERT INTO TB1 values (0,1,2,'d1','d2','d3','g1','g2',0.0,1.0,null,null,Null,NUll,Null)
    INSERT INTO TB1 values (0,1,2,'d1','d2','d3','g1','g2',0.0,1.0,null,null,Null,NUll,Null)
    INSERT INTO TB1 values (0,1,2,'d1','d2','d3','g1','g2',0.0,1.0,null,null,Null,NUll,Null)
    INSERT INTO TB1 values (0,1,2,'d1','d2','d3','g1','g2',0.0,1.0,null,null,Null,NUll,Null)


    CREATE TABLE TB2 
    (
       ABC int ,
       ABC1 int, 
       ABC2 int,
       DEF varchar(30),
       DEF1 varchar(30),
       DEF2 varchar(30),
       GHI varchar(30),
       GHI1 varchar(30),
       JKL numeric,
       JKL1 numeric,
       MNO datetime,
       MNO1 datetime,
       NOTEXIST varchar(30),
       NOTEXIST1 varchar(30), 
       NOTEXIST2 varchar(30)  
    )

    INSERT INTO TB2 values (0,1,2,'d1','d2','d3','g1','g2',0.0,1.0,null,null,Null,NUll,Null)
    INSERT INTO TB2 values (0,1,2,'d1','d2','d3','g1','g2',0.0,1.0,null,null,Null,NUll,Null)
    INSERT INTO TB2 values (0,1,2,'d1','d2','d3','g1','g2',0.0,1.0,null,null,Null,NUll,Null)
    INSERT INTO TB2 values (0,1,2,'d1','d2','d3','g1','g2',0.0,1.0,null,null,Null,NUll,Null)
```

4. Requirement: I want to automate the below manual steps in a single execution using loops/variables. I tried defining a variable but it is not working.

   a. Select the CName values from TblMaster that have a Flag = 1.

   ```
   Select CName from TblMaster where FLAG = 1

   This yields result:
   DEF
   GHI
   JKL
   MNO
   ```

   b. Use the results in 4.a above to identify Column Names in other tables in the DB with Similar string content (values).
       Below code snipped selects for the value of 'DEF'

   ```
   SELECT t.name AS table_name,c.name AS column_name
   FROM sys.tables AS t
   INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
   WHERE c.name LIKE '%DEF%' and t.name in ('TB1','TB2')
   ORDER BY  table_name;

   This yields result:

   table_name  column_name
   TB1             DEF
   TB1             DEF1
   TB1             DEF2
   TB2             DEF
   TB2             DEF1
   TB2             DEF2

   Similarly repeat the above for 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO'.
   ```

   c. Drop the columns in the tables identified in step 4.b (all results).

   ```
   ALTER TABLE TB1
   DROP COLUMN 
   DEF,DEF1,DEF2,GHI,GHI1,JKL, JKL1,MNO,MNO1

   ALTER TABLE TB2
   DROP COLUMN 
   DEF,DEF1,DEF2,GHI,GHI1,JKL, JKL1,MNO,MNO1
   ```

Thanks in advance!!

Below is what I tried but it is not working. Please help.

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0 
DECLARE @tempcnt INT = 1
DECLARE @tempcname varchar(30)

/* Find the max number of count for which we need to check other tables */

SELECT @cnt = COUNT (*) FROM TblMaster WHERE flag = 1

/* Create a temporary table with Row Number and the Column that we need */

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS id, CName 
INTO #TempTable
FROM (SELECT * FROM TblMaster WHERE flag = 1) t;

/* Loop through the temporary table to process each CName */

WHILE @tempcnt <= @cnt
BEGIN
  SELECT @tempcname = CName 
  FROM #TempTable WHERE id = @tempcnt     
  /* PRINT @tempcname */ 

/* Identify the Columns that have CName string as Column Name in other 
   tables */
ALTER TABLE TB1
DROP COLUMN 
(
SELECT c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE %@tempcname% and t.name = TB1
)

ALTER TABLE TB2
DROP COLUMN 
(
SELECT c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE %@tempcname% and t.name = TB2
)
SET @tempcnt = @tempcnt + 1;
END;

DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this procedure works as expected.

Have a look at fiddle, (you'll find a link at bottom).

I've used a double dynamic query.

First one returns a list of comma separated of similar columns.

```
SELECT @columns = STUFF((SELECT ',' + COLUMN_NAME 
                      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                      WHERE  (COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%DEF%' OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%GHI%' OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%JKL%' OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%MNO%') AND TABLE_NAME = 'TB1'
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Second query alter table by dropping columns:

```
ALTER TABLE TB1 DROP COLUMN DEF,DEF1,DEF2,GHI,GHI1,JKL,JKL1,MNO,MNO1
```

This is the function:

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DropColumns(@table_name NVARCHAR(128))
> AS
> BEGIN
>
>     DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
>     DECLARE @colsOR NVARCHAR(MAX);
>     DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
>
>     -- filter used in WHERE clause (COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%REF%' OR ...)
>     SET @colsOR = STUFF((SELECT ' OR ' + CONCAT('COLUMN_NAME LIKE ''%', CName, '%''') 
>                          FROM TblMaster
>                          WHERE FLAG = 1
>                          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 4, '');
>
>     -- columns returned separated by comma DEF,DEF1,DEF2,GHI,GHI1,JKL,JKL1,MNO,MNO1
>     SET @cmd = 'SELECT @columns = STUFF((SELECT '','' + COLUMN_NAME 
>                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
>                       WHERE  (' + @colsOR + ') AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @table_name + '''
>                       FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 1, '''')'
>
>     EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@columns NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @columns = @cols OUTPUT;
>
>     SET @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table_name + ' DROP COLUMN ' + @cols;
>
>     EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;
>
>     RETURN 0;
>
> END
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> EXEC dbo.DropColumns @table_name = 'TB1';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> --check results
> SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
> FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
> WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'TB1';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME
> :--------- | :----------
> TB1        | ABC        
> TB1        | ABC1       
> TB1        | ABC2       
> TB1        | NOTEXIST   
> TB1        | NOTEXIST1  
> TB1        | NOTEXIST2
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e91cae85923f3a81a4b3e6045333cf5f)*

Comment: Thanks a lot... it worked! Appreciate your help! Additionally I want to delete the Columns in table TB1/TB2 that have NULL in all rows and the Column Name is not in TblMaster. Is there a quick way to do this? So I want to delete NOTEXIST, NOTEXIST1 and NOTEXIST2 because they are all NULL and they do not exist in TblMaster. This could be a separate query and does not have to be in the above solution. Thanks again!